# After SQLite update: Unable to find an entry point named 'sqlite3_changes_interop' in DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'

Tags: c#, sqlite, dll, dllimport, system.data.sqlite

My C#/SQLite was working fine until I decided to update the SQLite DLLs (from 1.0.82.0 to 1.0.84.0). Now I get this crash:

> Unable to find an entry point named 'sqlite3_changes_interop' in DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>SparkleShare.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.EntryPointNotFoundException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Unable to find an entry point named 'sqlite3_changes_interop' in DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_changes_interop(IntPtr db)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.get_Changes()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteStatement.TryGetChanges(Int32&amp;amp; changes)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The code has not changed, so I don't think it is a code problem ([here is the line](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/CmisSync/blob/master/SparkleLib/Cmis/CmisDatabase.cs#L178) where it happens, anyway).

Is there something wrong with the new version I downloaded? I downloaded `sqlite-netFx40-static-binary-Win32-2010-1.0.84.0.zip` at the `Precompiled Statically-Linked Binaries for 32-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.0)` paragraph at http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

EDIT: I reverted back to the previous DLLs, but the problem still happens, maybe because Visual C# has some cache somewhere that does not get cleaned.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure that the SQLite.Interop.dll in both the x64 and the x86 folders of your project have been updated to version 1.0.84.0.

Comment: And that you don't have two versions installed - was the problem in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I guest you should to update Sqlite libraries from Nuget Package Manager. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Source Control ? So you can rollback your file on its working state.

Clean and Build your solution then set your SQLite.Interop.DLL as copy to newer. and make sure that it is located on your bin file.

Regards

Comment: Yes, the source code, VS project and DLLs are all on Git. In my `EDIT` paragraph when I wrote `I reverted back to the previous DLLs` it meant reverting using Git. So I am sure it is the same DLLs as before.