# System.EntryPointNotFoundException + Could not install package 'SQLite.Interop.dll 1.0.103'. my project targets'.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, nuget, package-managers

I have a working project I downloaded from source control. It uses the nuget package sqlite-net-pcl. It runs fine by itself. When I change the startup project to my own project(which calls the project above, and has no packages of its own), however, the code dies when I call

```
dbConnection.Open();
```

on an oject:

```
dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dbFile + ";Version=3;");
```

with the error message:

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point named 'sqlite3_open_interop' in DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'
```

When I look this message up online I get results like the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396656/after-sqlite-update-unable-to-find-an-entry-point-named-sqlite3-changes-intero) telling me to install/update SQLite.Interop.dll, however, neither the version suggested, or the latest version seem to be compatible with either the .net version in the original project, or the version of the project I am trying to include (.net version 4.5.2 or 4.6.1)

What's more, the original error seems odd given that all I've really done is change startup project...
Any ideas here would be good - I'm about ready to come back home to Kansas from the dark and awful world of package managers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that if I want to use packages from my existing project when calling from the new startup project, then I need to have the libraries installed there as well. I just copied all packages by copying packages.config to my new project and then ran

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

in nuget package manager for the new project.